# Why graph of parabola in which discrimant is negative is upwards?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Why graph of parabola in which discriminant is negative is upwards? consider equation $ y =x^2  + x + 2$. Discrimant is neagtive and so graph is upwards. why is that so ? what is analytical explanation>?

Comment: The "way in which the parabola points" is determined by the coefficient of the $x^2$ term, not the discriminant.

Comment: Why and How?...

Comment: The discriminant of $y=-x^2-x-2$ is also negative, but the graph is downwards.

Comment: For large $x$, the sign of the trinomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is decided by the dominant term, $ax^2$, that has the sign of $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing the square,
$$ ax^2+bx+c = a\left( x + \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 + \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} $$
The last term contains the discriminant, which only tells you when the parabola can intersect the $x$-axis: the first term is a square, so is always nonnegative.

The first term is a shift in the variable $x$, and we see that it looks like a rescaled shift of $x^2$ if $a>0$, and $-x^2$ if $a<0$. Hence the "upwardness" or "downwardness" of the parabola is determined by the sign of $a$.

Intuitively, $c$ can't tell you anything about how the parabola behaves as $x$ varies, since it only occurs in a term that does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Rectification: in $y=ax^2+bx+c$ , the parabola points according to the direction of a. It is related to the concavity and convexity of the curve.
Here. $f^"(x)=2a$. When $a>0$ then the $f(x)$ is concave upwards and if $a<0$ then concave downwards.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant only gives you information about the roots of the quadratic equation. If your parabola is given by:

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

There are 2 possibilities:

$a <0$:

The parabola's vertex is upwards

$a > 0$:

The parabola's vertex is downwards.

This can be shown using second derivative.

Comment: It would be better to say vertex than top.  If $a > 0$, the parabola opens upwards, so it does not have a top.

Comment: Will edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then we have $f^{'}(x) = 2ax + b$

Let $b > 0$

For $x < -b/2a$ we have $f^{'} (x) < 0$ if $a > 0$ since $2ax + b < 2a(-b/2a) + b = 0$. Therefore the function is decreasing.

Now let $x > -b/2a$ then we have $f^{'}(x) > 0$ if $a > 0$ and the function is increasing .

Hence we get ${x \to \pm \infty} \implies f(x) \to  \infty$ and we a upward graph.

Similarly we get ${x \to \pm \infty} \implies f(x) \to  -\infty$ for $a < 0$ and a downward parabola.

---

Now in comments you asked why sign of $b,c$ does not matter, sign of $c$ does not matter because it is not in the derivative and sign of $b$ does not matter because an inequality does not reverse if we add or subtract by any real number.
(In $2ax < 2a(-b/2a)$ if we add any number the nature of inequality will be same).